# Count number of pairs in list disregarding order

Tags: python, list, collections, tuples, counter

In example, if I have the following script:

```
import collections

lst = [['a','b'],['b','a'],['c','d'],['c','d'],['d','c']]

print([(a, b, v) for (a, b),v in collections.Counter(map(tuple,lst)).items()])
```

I get as output:

```
[('a', 'b', 1), ('b', 'a', 1), ('c', 'd', 2), ('d', 'c', 1)]
```

Can I adapt my code to yield the following output:

```
[('a', 'b', 2), ('c', 'd', 3)]
```

So a function that doesn't include the order of the pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just sort each element in the list before counting, like so:

```
import collections

lst = [['a','b'],['b','a'],['c','d'],['c','d'],['d','c']]

sorted_lst = [sorted(x) for x in lst]

print([(a, b, v) for (a, b),v in collections.Counter(map(tuple,sorted_lst)).items()])
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'b', 2), ('c', 'd', 3)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a data structure that doesn't care about order. In this case you'll need `frozenset` instead of a regular `set` because `Counter` requires it to be hashable. But basically it's a simple substitution of `tuple` in your original code for `frozenset`:

```
print([(a, b, v) for (a, b),v in collections.Counter(map(frozenset,lst)).items()])
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'b', 2), ('d', 'c', 3)]
```

Comment: Seems like the most sensible way to go; if you're trying to ignore sorting, then an unsorted datatype seems to be the most appropriate. The accepted answer ignores sorting by forcing it to always be the same, which seems like a slightly less literal translation of the actual problem

Answer (score 2):

Sorting the list before you get collections of it solves the problem.

```
import collections

lst = [['a','b'],['b','a'],['c','d'],['c','d'],['d','c']]

sort_list = sorted(x) for x in lst

print([(a, b, v) for (a, b),v in collections.Counter(map(tuple,sort_list)).items()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the values of the key `a,b` and use `groupby` in `itertools` and then `sum` all the elements in the group.

```
import itertools as it
lst = [['a','b'],['b','a'],['c','d'],['c','d'],['d','c']]
output = [(*group,sum(1 for i in elements)) for group,elements in it.groupby(lst,key=lambda x:sorted(x))]
print(output)
```

OUTPUT

```
[('a', 'b', 2), ('c', 'd', 3)]
```